# Why is one of my SQL tables not allowing me to update in spreadsheet view in MS Access?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, ms-access, ms-access-2010

**Situation**:

- I have quite a few tables created in SQL
- These tables are linked to MS Access
- I can very easily "add" new entries to all but **one** of the tables

  - This table includes a `Foreign key` reference (but so do others)
- All tables are created the same way and linked the same way

**Problem**:

- I cannot add entries in the Spreadsheet View in Access. Generally you have some sort of entry like (where there is a * as well as empty row beneath the table you can click in and begin typing)

  - [image]
- However this table looks like:

  - [image]
- Right clicking on a record has "New Record" and "Delete Record" grayed out, while I can use this on other tables

I am creating the table using:

```
CREATE TABLE ProjectApprovers (
    ProjectCode varchar(50) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ProjectCodes(ProjectCode),
    RACFApprover varchar(50)
);
```

The reason I am confused is that it does not appear to be a SQL permissions problem because I can run the following code in Access:

```
INSERT INTO ProjectApprovers (ProjectCode,RACFApprover) VALUES ('ValidProjectCode','test123');
```

It seems these restrictions are only limited to the spreadsheet view. Additionally, identical syntax is used to create other tables which do not have this problem.

I am using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1590236/1048539) to link my database tables.

Is something like this a permission problem? I have never referenced this problem table with permissions.

Comment: From Access' point of view, does it think the linked table `ProjectApprovers` includes a primary key?  (You can check by opening the linked table in Design View.)  If Access doesn't recognize a primary key, it will present the data as read-only.

Comment: @HansUp no it does not, that must be the problem

Comment: Modify the table in SQL Server to include a primary key.  Then re-link the table in Access so it will notice the change.  BTW, I don't understand the justification for a downvote on this question.  I upvoted.

Comment: Also - low chance of whoever downvoted this indicating why, but I would also appreciate knowing why this received a downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Access doesn't recognize a primary key in the linked table, it will present the table as read-only in Datasheet View.

Fix this by adding a primary key in SQL Server.  Then recreate the link in Access so it can notice the changed table structure.